# IF statement for LINUX

Tags: linux, if-statement, echo

Modify your program so that if no matching name is found, a message is displayed: "Name 'xyz' not in directory". You could use an 'if' statement to check the value of $? to see if the grep command was successful (remember that '0' indicates success). If the grep is NOT successful, then echo the message (which includes the value of $name).

The original code was:

```
#!/bin/bash

name=$1

if [ "$name" = "" ]
then echo -n "Enter a name to search for: "

read name

fi

grep -I $name ~uli101/2017a/phonebook
```

I basically have to insert and IF statement into the program using the instructions above. I've tried many different things such as:

```
if [ $? = 1 ]
then echo -n "Name 'xyz' not in directory"
fi
```

but it is not accepting the answer. Pls help me out with this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me, try:

```
#!/bin/bash

name=$1

if [ "$name" = "" ]; then
   echo -n "Enter a name to search for: "

   read name
fi

grep -I $name phonebook

if [ $? = 1 ]; then
   echo "Name '${name}' not in directory"   
fi
```

Or you can change the last IF into:

```
grep -I $name phonebook && echo -n "Name not in directory"
```

Comment: @KyleMathews I modified the answer, try again

Comment: I tried submitting that as well, but their seems to be a mistake in the IF statement. Any other solutions?

Comment: The echo part is fine, its just the 'if [ $? = 1 ]' part which needs fixing. I've been stuck on this for 2 hours now and am almost ready to give up lol.

Comment: did you put the ;

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me.

```
#!/bin/bash
#

NAME=$1

if [ -z "${NAME}" ]; then
    echo -n "Enter a name to search for: "
    read NAME
fi

grep -I $NAME~uli101/2017a/phonebook
```